# R Shiny: Reset selectizeInput selection upon actionButton input

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to reset selectizeInput selections upon actionButton input.

Please see the following code, in which I cannot get the eventReactive to function:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  column(width = 4,algin = "center", uiOutput("choose_Number")) ,
  br(),
  column(width = 4, algin = "center",div(
    align = "center", actionButton('delete','Delete Number(s)',style="color: #fff; background-color: #53C1BE")))
  
  
  
  
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  
  output$choose_Number <- renderUI({
    selectizeInput("choose_Number", "Select Number", as.list(c(1,2,3,4)),selected = c(''), options=list(create=TRUE,'plugins' = list('remove_button'),
                                                                                               persist = FALSE), multiple = TRUE)
  })
  
  ##### I am trying to reset the selectizeInput upon input from the Delete button
  eventReactive(input$delete, {updateSelectizeInput("choose_Number", "Select Number", as.list(c(1,2,3,4)), selected = c(''),options=list(create=TRUE,'plugins' = list('remove_button'),
                                                                                                                 persist = FALSE), multiple = TRUE)} )
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Thank you.

Comment: `observeEvent` is a better choice instead of `eventReactive`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The biggest issue was that the session was missing. You can omit the `session` argument if you want to but then you need to name all other arguments because `session` is the first in line. Second issue was that you can set `multiple` in `selectizeInput`  but not later when using `updateSelectizeInput()` to change it.

Minor improvements: the manual recommends using `character()` to deselect the current choice. As mentioned by @YBS you do not provide a reactive value so that `observeEvent` is the better choice here.

PS: are you sure you want to centre align the columns? It looks strange.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  column(width = 4, align = "center", uiOutput("choose_Number")),
  br(),
  column(width = 4, align = "center", div(
    align = "center", 
    actionButton('delete', 'Delete Number(s)', style="color: #fff; background-color: #53C1BE"))
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    
  output$choose_Number <- renderUI({
    selectizeInput("choose_Number", "Select Number", as.list(c(1,2,3,4)), selected = character(), 
                   options = list(create=TRUE,'plugins' = list('remove_button'), persist = FALSE), 
                   multiple = TRUE)
  })
  
  ##### I am trying to reset the selectizeInput upon input from the Delete button
  observeEvent(input$delete, {
    updateSelectizeInput(session, "choose_Number", choices = as.list(1:4), 
                         selected = character(0),
                         options = list(create=TRUE, 'plugins' = list('remove_button'), persist = FALSE))
    })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Excellent. Thanks very much, @Jan and YBS.